# how can i overlay div to

Tags: javascript, background, html5-canvas, overlay

**how can i remove my overlay background div with mouse move with mouse radius area**, i attached my code for demo...  pls solved any one and help me thank you.  any one create this type of structure for my website

```js
    var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
    $(document).mousemove(function (e) {
        mouseX = e.pageX;
        mouseY = e.pageY;
    });

    // cache the selector
    var follower = $(".follower");
    var xp = 0, yp = 0;
    var loop = setInterval(function () {
        // change 12 to alter damping higher is slower
        xp += (mouseX - xp) / 12;
        yp += (mouseY - yp) / 12;
        follower.css({ left: xp, top: yp,  opacity:1});
        //$(follower).css({  });
    }, 30);


    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".divStick").click(function () {
            $(".divOverlay").addClass("overlayStick");
            $(this).addClass("active");

            if ($(".divOverlay").hasClass("overlay")) {
                $(".divOverlay").removeClass("overlay");
            }
            if ($(".divOverlay").hasClass("overlayShoes")) {
                $(".divShoes").removeClass("active");
                $(".divOverlay").removeClass("overlayShoes");
            }
        });

        $(".divShoes").click(function () {
            $(".divOverlay").addClass("overlayShoes");
            $(this).addClass("active");

            if ($(".divOverlay").hasClass("overlay")) {
                $(".divOverlay").removeClass("overlay");
            }
            if ($(".divOverlay").hasClass("overlayStick")) {
                $(".divOverlay").removeClass("overlayStick");
                $(".divStick").removeClass("active");
            }
        });

    });
```

```css
<style>
    .txt {
    }

    .overlay {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
        z-index: 9999;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
    }

        .overlay:before {
            content: '';
            display: inline-block;
            height: 100%;
            vertical-align: middle;
            margin-right: -0.25em;
        }



    .overlayStick {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: #000;
        z-index: 9999;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: url(stick2.png), auto;
    }

        .overlayStick:before {
            content: '';
            display: inline-block;
            height: 100%;
            vertical-align: middle;
            margin-right: -0.25em;
        }

    .overlayShoes {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: #000;
        z-index: 9999;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: url(shoes.png), auto;
    }

        .overlayShoes:before {
            content: '';
            display: inline-block;
            height: 100%;
            vertical-align: middle;
            margin-right: -0.25em;
        }

    .txt {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        position: relative;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: #C90;
    }

        .txt:hover {
            background-color: #900;
            cursor: pointer !important;
        }
  .tx {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        position: relative;
        font-weight: bold;
        
    }
    .active {
        background-color: #900;
    }

    .new {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        position: relative;
        font-weight: bold;
    }


    .overlay2 {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .overlay2 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        z-index: 9999;
        color: white;
    }

        .overlay2:before {
            content: '';
            display: inline-block;
            height: 100%;
            vertical-align: middle;
            margin-right: -0.25em;
        }

    /*.overlay2 {
        color: #fff;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: url(shoes.png), auto;
    }*/

    .new a {
        color: #fff;
    }

    .txt a {
        color: #fff;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .follower {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        color: #fff;
        height: 80px;
        width: 80px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        -webkit-filter: blur(15px);
        -moz-filter: blur(15px);
        -o-filter: blur(15px);
        -ms-filter: blur(15px);
        filter: blur(15px);
    }

    /*.follower {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        color: #fff;
        height: 150px;
        width: 150px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        -webkit-filter: blur(15px);
        -moz-filter: blur(15px);
        -o-filter: blur(15px);
        -ms-filter: blur(15px);
        filter: blur(15px);
    }*/


 
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="box medium">
        <h1>overlay div remove with mouse move</h1>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
        <div class="divOverlay overlay">
            <div class="txt divStick"><a href="#">Stick</a></div>
            &nbsp;
            <div class="txt divShoes"><a href="#">Shoes</a></div>
            <div class="follower"></div>
            <div class="tx">TAKE SOMEOTHER TIME </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: i don't really get what you mean by 'remove overlay'... are you trying to make the white dot transparent, so you can see the page below the overlay there?

Comment: i actually want to cut overlay where my mouse pointer is hover,and background text should be visible

Comment: you also create with your code, not used my code....

Comment: are you trying to make the white dot transparent, so you can see the page below the overlay there?,yes [can you make this?]